# Matlab class properties as handles, nested handles and class initialization/constructor and preallocation

Tags: matlab, class, properties, handle, pre-allocation

I have been wondering how user defined Matlab classes as handle subclasses works. It seems, and also from what I read, that in some cases they reference to each other that might be unexpected or misleading and causing bugs. I have encountered this problem mainly during preallocation of these user defined classes. It seems to me, that a working solution might be using the approach of Btest, see below, however this solution is more nasty (as Atest or Ctest) make the code more clean and also it is more time costly.
Lets look at the code first. Lets say I have four classes, each one is a subclass of Matlab handle class. Now pay attention that the first three classes have a property CXp3 that contains a scalar handle or **an array** of handles to the other consecutive classes. Also, the classes contain constructors, where this third property CXp3 is defined again (so that is the initialization during constructing the class, whereas the default initialization in properties is during the first compiling of  that class).

```
classdef MyClass1 < handle
    properties
        C1p1(1,1) {mustBeNumeric};
        C1p2 = 1;
        C1p3(1,:) = MyClass2;
    end
    methods
        function obj = MyClass1()
            % MyClass1 constructor function
            obj.C1p2 = 4;
            obj.C1p3(1,:) = MyClass2;
        end
    end
end
```

```
classdef MyClass2 < handle
    properties
        C2p1(1,1) {mustBeNumeric};
        C2p2 = 2;
        C2p3(1,:) = MyClass3;
    end
    methods
        function obj = MyClass2()
            % MyClass2 constructor function
            obj.C2p2 = 5;
            obj.C2p3(1,:) = MyClass3;
        end
        function ChangeC2p3(obj,Number)
            obj.C2p3(1,Number) = MyClass3;
        end
    end
end
```

```
classdef MyClass3 < handle
    properties
        C3p1(1,1) {mustBeNumeric};
        C3p2 = 3;
        C3p3(1,:) = MyClass4;
    end
    methods
        function obj = MyClass3()
            % MyClass3 constructor function
            obj.C3p2 = 6;
            obj.C3p3(1,:) = MyClass4;
        end
        function ChangeC3p3(obj,Number)
            obj.C3p3(1,Number) = MyClass4;
        end
    end
end
```

```
classdef MyClass4 < handle
    properties
        C4p1(1,1) {mustBeNumeric};
        C4p2 = 4;
    end
    methods
        function obj = MyClass4()
            % MyClass4 constructor function
            obj.C4p2 = 8;
        end
    end
end
```

Now lets test their behaviour, and especially, when we want to create an array of the classes including the first class. Lets create an array of the first MyClass1

```
Num = 10000;
tic
Atest(1,Num) = MyClass1;
toc
clear A

tic
Btest(1,Num) = MyClass1;
for m = 1:1:Num
    Btest(m) = MyClass1;
end
toc

tic
Ctest = repmat(MyClass1,1,Num);
toc
```

the answer to this is

```
Elapsed time is 0.036575 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.618905 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.002550 seconds.
```

Here it can been seen, that Btest took the longest, whereas the Atest or Ctest, that are more likely to be recomended by Matlab documentation, are much faster. However, the fun part starts once we start working with different array elements and with their nested properties. Lets say I want to use `function ChangeC2p3(obj,Number)` of `MyClass2` to the first element of Xtest array. I would suppose that it will change only the `C2p3` property of the first element of Xtest(1), however it will change multiple. To track the changes, lets have a code:

```
MyNum = 10;

L1 = length(Atest(1).C1p3.C2p3);
L2 = length(Atest(2).C1p3.C2p3);
L3 = length(Atest(3).C1p3.C2p3);
L4 = length(Atest(end).C1p3.C2p3);
fprintf('\nThe length of Atest(X).C1p3.C2p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: %d, %d, %d, %d',L1,L2,L3,L4)
% now run the function
Atest(1).C1p3.ChangeC2p3(MyNum)
L1 = length(Atest(1).C1p3.C2p3);
L2 = length(Atest(2).C1p3.C2p3);
L3 = length(Atest(3).C1p3.C2p3);
L4 = length(Atest(end).C1p3.C2p3);
fprintf('\nThe length of Atest(X).C1p3.C2p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: %d, %d, %d, %d',L1,L2,L3,L4)
fprintf('\n')

L1 = length(Btest(1).C1p3.C2p3);
L2 = length(Btest(2).C1p3.C2p3);
L3 = length(Btest(3).C1p3.C2p3);
L4 = length(Btest(end).C1p3.C2p3);
fprintf('\nThe length of Btest(X).C1p3.C2p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: %d, %d, %d, %d',L1,L2,L3,L4)
% now run the function
Btest(1).C1p3.ChangeC2p3(MyNum)
L1 = length(Btest(1).C1p3.C2p3);
L2 = length(Btest(2).C1p3.C2p3);
L3 = length(Btest(3).C1p3.C2p3);
L4 = length(Btest(end).C1p3.C2p3);
fprintf('\nThe length of Btest(X).C1p3.C2p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: %d, %d, %d, %d',L1,L2,L3,L4)
fprintf('\n')

L1 = length(Ctest(1).C1p3.C2p3);
L2 = length(Ctest(2).C1p3.C2p3);
L3 = length(Ctest(3).C1p3.C2p3);
L4 = length(Ctest(end).C1p3.C2p3);
fprintf('\nThe length of Ctest(X).C1p3.C2p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: %d, %d, %d, %d',L1,L2,L3,L4)
% now run the function
Ctest(1).C1p3.ChangeC2p3(MyNum)
L1 = length(Ctest(1).C1p3.C2p3);
L2 = length(Ctest(2).C1p3.C2p3);
L3 = length(Ctest(3).C1p3.C2p3);
L4 = length(Ctest(end).C1p3.C2p3);
fprintf('\nThe length of Ctest(X).C1p3.C2p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: %d, %d, %d, %d',L1,L2,L3,L4)
fprintf('\n')
```

Where the lengths have changed to multiple elements of these arrays.

```
The length of Atest(X).C1p3.C2p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: 1, 1, 1, 1
The length of Atest(X).C1p3.C2p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: 10, 10, 10, 1

The length of Btest(X).C1p3.C2p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: 1, 1, 1, 1
The length of Btest(X).C1p3.C2p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: 10, 1, 1, 1

The length of Ctest(X).C1p3.C2p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: 1, 1, 1, 1
The length of Ctest(X).C1p3.C2p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: 10, 10, 10, 10
```

It can be also proved that the elements reference to each other when we change the value of the first element in Xtest(1) of its nested handle `C3p1=10` by this code

```
N1 = Atest(1).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
N2 = Atest(2).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
N3 = Atest(3).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
N4 = Atest(end).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
fprintf('\nAtest Before: %d, %d, %d, %d',N1,N2,N3,N4)

N1 = Btest(1).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
N2 = Btest(2).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
N3 = Btest(3).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
N4 = Btest(end).C1p3.C2p3(end).C3p1;
fprintf('\nBtest Before: %d, %d, %d, %d',N1,N2,N3,N4)

N1 = Ctest(1).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
N2 = Ctest(2).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
N3 = Ctest(3).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
N4 = Ctest(end).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
fprintf('\nCtest Before: %d, %d, %d, %d',N1,N2,N3,N4)
fprintf('\n')

% now change the value of property a see the effect 
Atest(1).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p1 = 10;
N1 = Atest(1).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
N2 = Atest(2).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
N3 = Atest(3).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
N4 = Atest(end).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
fprintf('\nAtest After: %d, %d, %d, %d',N1,N2,N3,N4)

Btest(1).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p1 = 10;
N1 = Btest(1).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
N2 = Btest(2).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
N3 = Btest(3).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
N4 = Btest(end).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
fprintf('\nAtest After: %d, %d, %d, %d',N1,N2,N3,N4)

Ctest(1).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p1 = 10;
N1 = Ctest(1).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
N2 = Ctest(2).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
N3 = Ctest(3).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
N4 = Ctest(end).C1p3.C2p3.C3p1;
fprintf('\nCtest After: %d, %d, %d, %d',N1,N2,N3,N4)
fprintf('\n')
```

And we will get answer

```
Atest Before: 0, 0, 0, 0
Btest Before: 0, 0, 0, 0
Ctest Before: 0, 0, 0, 0

Atest After: 10, 10, 10, 0
Atest After: 10, 0, 0, 0
Ctest After: 10, 10, 10, 10
```

This is quite interesting as it can be seen, that `Atest(1,Num) = MyClass1` has 1:(end-1) elements referencing to one instance of that class, all `repmat(MyClass1,1,Num)` elements referencing only to one instance and only the `Btest` referencing to separate instances (anyway that is what I wanted and would have been expected from the other two). Now interestingly enough, this behaviour applies also somehow to the nested class handles. Lets change the size of third layer classes of the first element of classes with

```
MyNum = 5;

L1 = length(Atest(1).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L2 = length(Atest(2).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L3 = length(Atest(3).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L4 = length(Atest(end).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
fprintf('\nThe length of Atest(X).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: %d, %d, %d, %d',L1,L2,L3,L4)
% now run the function
Atest(1).C1p3.C2p3(1).ChangeC3p3(MyNum)
L1 = length(Atest(1).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L2 = length(Atest(2).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L3 = length(Atest(3).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L4 = length(Atest(end).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
fprintf('\nThe length of Atest(X).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: %d, %d, %d, %d',L1,L2,L3,L4)
fprintf('\n')

L1 = length(Btest(1).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L2 = length(Btest(2).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L3 = length(Btest(3).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L4 = length(Btest(end).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
fprintf('\nThe length of Btest(X).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: %d, %d, %d, %d',L1,L2,L3,L4)
% now run the function
Btest(1).C1p3.C2p3(1).ChangeC3p3(MyNum)
L1 = length(Btest(1).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L2 = length(Btest(2).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L3 = length(Btest(3).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L4 = length(Btest(end).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
fprintf('\nThe length of Btest(X).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: %d, %d, %d, %d',L1,L2,L3,L4)
fprintf('\n')

L1 = length(Ctest(1).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L2 = length(Ctest(2).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L3 = length(Ctest(3).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L4 = length(Ctest(end).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
fprintf('\nThe length of Ctest(X).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: %d, %d, %d, %d',L1,L2,L3,L4)
% now run the function
Ctest(1).C1p3.C2p3(1).ChangeC3p3(MyNum)
L1 = length(Ctest(1).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L2 = length(Ctest(2).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L3 = length(Ctest(3).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L4 = length(Ctest(end).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
fprintf('\nThe length of Ctest(X).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: %d, %d, %d, %d',L1,L2,L3,L4)
fprintf('\n')
```

The referencing will behave the same between Xtest(X) elements.

```
The length of Atest(X).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: 1, 1, 1, 1
The length of Atest(X).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: 5, 5, 5, 1

The length of Btest(X).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: 1, 1, 1, 1
The length of Btest(X).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: 5, 1, 1, 1

The length of Ctest(X).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: 1, 1, 1, 1
The length of Ctest(X).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: 5, 5, 5, 5
```

However, for the one element of the first layer class, then the third layer property `CP3p3` after using `ChangeC3p3` in the array reference each to a seprate class instance. The code:

```
MyNum = 7;

L1 = length(Atest(1).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L2 = length(Atest(1).C1p3.C2p3(2).C3p3);
L3 = length(Atest(1).C1p3.C2p3(3).C3p3);
L4 = length(Atest(1).C1p3.C2p3(end).C3p3);
fprintf('\nThe length of Atest(1).C1p3.C2p3(X).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: %d, %d, %d, %d',L1,L2,L3,L4)
% now run the function
Atest(1).C1p3.C2p3(1).ChangeC3p3(MyNum)
L1 = length(Atest(1).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L2 = length(Atest(1).C1p3.C2p3(2).C3p3);
L3 = length(Atest(1).C1p3.C2p3(3).C3p3);
L4 = length(Atest(1).C1p3.C2p3(end).C3p3);
fprintf('\nThe length of Atest(1).C1p3.C2p3(X).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: %d, %d, %d, %d',L1,L2,L3,L4)
fprintf('\n')

L1 = length(Btest(1).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L2 = length(Btest(1).C1p3.C2p3(2).C3p3);
L3 = length(Btest(1).C1p3.C2p3(3).C3p3);
L4 = length(Btest(1).C1p3.C2p3(end).C3p3);
fprintf('\nThe length of Btest(1).C1p3.C2p3(X).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: %d, %d, %d, %d',L1,L2,L3,L4)
% now run the function
Btest(1).C1p3.C2p3(1).ChangeC3p3(MyNum)
L1 = length(Btest(1).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L2 = length(Btest(1).C1p3.C2p3(2).C3p3);
L3 = length(Btest(1).C1p3.C2p3(3).C3p3);
L4 = length(Btest(1).C1p3.C2p3(end).C3p3);
fprintf('\nThe length of Btest(1).C1p3.C2p3(X).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: %d, %d, %d, %d',L1,L2,L3,L4)
fprintf('\n')

L1 = length(Ctest(1).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L2 = length(Ctest(1).C1p3.C2p3(2).C3p3);
L3 = length(Ctest(1).C1p3.C2p3(3).C3p3);
L4 = length(Ctest(1).C1p3.C2p3(end).C3p3);
fprintf('\nThe length of Ctest(1).C1p3.C2p3(X).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: %d, %d, %d, %d',L1,L2,L3,L4)
% now run the function
Ctest(1).C1p3.C2p3(1).ChangeC3p3(MyNum)
L1 = length(Ctest(1).C1p3.C2p3(1).C3p3);
L2 = length(Ctest(1).C1p3.C2p3(2).C3p3);
L3 = length(Ctest(1).C1p3.C2p3(3).C3p3);
L4 = length(Ctest(1).C1p3.C2p3(end).C3p3);
fprintf('\nThe length of Ctest(1).C1p3.C2p3(X).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: %d, %d, %d, %d',L1,L2,L3,L4)
fprintf('\n')
```

With the answer

```
The length of Atest(1).C1p3.C2p3(X).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: 5, 1, 1, 1
The length of Atest(1).C1p3.C2p3(X).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: 7, 1, 1, 1

The length of Btest(1).C1p3.C2p3(X).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: 5, 1, 1, 1
The length of Btest(1).C1p3.C2p3(X).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: 7, 1, 1, 1

The length of Ctest(1).C1p3.C2p3(X).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: 5, 1, 1, 1
The length of Ctest(1).C1p3.C2p3(X).C3p3 is for X=1,2,3,end: 7, 1, 1, 1
```

The exmplanation is probably quite long and the question could have been shortened, however I tought that it could propably help others to get better understanidng and it also points to possible incorrect referencing. At this point I would rather weclome a comment on how one should preallocate an array of Matlab handles classes so, that each will be pointing to a separate instance of that class and also all its nested properties will be poinitng to a separate objects. From what I tried it seems that the Btest approach will do the work, however the preallocation took the longest and the code is not that clean, so the question might be, if there is a better way to do it?

Anyway some topics that might be of interest here are [here-stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52341447/property-initialization-in-matlab) or [here-undocumentedmatlab](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/articles/handle-object-as-default-class-property-value) or [here-undocumentedmatlab](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog_old/class-object-creation-performance).

Because I am quite new to OOP I might also not clearly understand some things about constructor etc. The interesting thing for exampele is, that if all the constructor function will be commented out, the answer to the code will be completly different and it seems that it might be equal to `Ctest = repmat(MyClass1,1,Num);` approach. Another thing I am not sure about, whether in constructor function has any role the bracket (1,:) as `obj.C3p3(1,:) = MyClass4;`. It seems it doesnt. Or for example if creating the object shoudl be rather `A = MyClass1` or `A = MyClass1()`? And whether the dimensions in property definition `C1p3(1,:) = MyClass2;` plays any role with what is later in constructor function. And one more comment, the problem cannot be solved by haveing `C1p3` insted of `C1p3(1,:) = MyClass2;` in properties and later on having `obj.C1p3(1,:) = MyClass2;` in constructor, because then the `Conversion to double from MyClass2 is not possible.` error will occure.

Comment: All copies of an object of a handle class share memory, they are basically pointers (handles) to the same underlying object. So `repmat` and the other approach create one object and copy it to all array elements. The only way to create N different handle objects is to call the constructor N times. Unless these objects encapsulate some resource that cannot be copied (a UI element, a file, a network connection), you should not be using handle classes. Use normal value semantics (normal in the context of MATLAB syntax), and all your worries will disappear.

Comment: Really, I cannot stress how much easier it is to use value classes. The only odd thing is that a method of the class cannot modify the object, it must return the modified object. So you do `a = a.modify()`, or rather more in line with MATLAB syntax, `a = modify(a)`. I think this is the reason people try to use handle classes for everything, but that is a mistake IMO.

Comment: You are probably right that using a value classes will help to solve the problem, however you will lose kind of advantage of probably OOP (or rather pointers), because then every time you will be sending an object to a function, Matlab will have to create a new copy of that object. Once out of the function you will have to always remember to overwrite your originally sended object in your code whats more of a programer problem rahter to performance one. Once the passing objects will become big, than the 'only value classes' approach will probably become quite performance burden @Cris Luengo

Comment: No, MATLAB is very well optimized, and built around the concept of value classes. They are the core of the language. So they are not going to be inefficient! MATLAB uses lazy copy optimization, and can even update an object (or array) when doing `a = function(a)`, without intermediate copies. Basically, you just forget about trying to manually optimize things, and trust the interpreter to do things for you. You just need to follow a few “best practices” to allow the interpreter to do its best work.

Answer (score 0):

**Respond to Comment:**

First of all, thank @Cris Luengo for his comments. I have tried to compare the speed between value class and handle class and I think it is not actually that bad, however by manually optimizing the code (saying the interpreter that this is a pointer and this is a value) you might get some speed advantage of about 30 %. But still, for some small cases the speeds are quite comparable. To test it I created two classes (one value, one handle), each having a property 2 of some size, and then call a function of its own another number of times.

```
classdef MyClass5
    properties
        C5p1(1,:) {mustBeNumeric};
        C5p2(:,:) {mustBeNumeric};
    end
    methods
        function obj = MyClass5(val)
            % MyClass5 constructor function
            obj.C5p2 = rand(val,val);
        end
        function obj = ChangeC5p1(obj,Number)
            obj.C5p1 = 1:1:Number;
        end
    end
end
```

```
classdef MyClass6 < handle
    properties
        C6p1(1,:) {mustBeNumeric};
        C6p2(:,:) {mustBeNumeric};
    end
    methods
        function obj = MyClass6(val)
            % MyClass6 constructor function
            obj.C6p2 = rand(val,val);
        end
        function ChangeC6p1(obj,Number)
            obj.C6p1 = 1:1:Number;
        end
    end
end
```

```
NumberRepetition = 200000;
ArrayLength = 100;
Arr2Length = 5000;

A = MyClass5(Arr2Length);
B = MyClass6(Arr2Length);

fprintf('\n The value class speed:')
tic
for m = 1:1:NumberRepetition
    A = A.ChangeC5p1(ArrayLength);
end
toc
fprintf('\n The handle class speed:')
tic
for m = 1:1:NumberRepetition
    B.ChangeC6p1(ArrayLength);
end
toc
```

And for the setting above, the answer is

```
 The value class speed:Elapsed time is 2.362391 seconds.
 The handle class speed:Elapsed time is 1.804626 seconds.
```

Have a Matlab 2020a version on now quite older i3 (~2017 CPU). If I guess correctly the second property has size of about 5000x5000*64 bits, that is about 190 MBs data held by the object. Interestinglly if the `NumberRepetition` is about the same size as `ArrayLength` the times become quite even. It is probably not the best way to compare the speeds, but it is true that I would be expecting worse results.

So it might still seem, that one way to avoid problem descirbed in the original post would be to use value class only with possible small speed downbreak, or try to handle the behaviour by using the Btest allocation approach every time an array of objects are created.

Comment: Is your reproduction code in a function file, or a script? That can make a difference to the optimisations that can be applied by MATLAB. (functions are almost always faster). I'm not sure if it's still the case, but using the "functional form" of method invocation used to be faster, i.e. `A = ChangeC5p1(A, ArrayLength)`. (This form might be unfamiliar to people used to C++ / Java style method invocation, but has always been supported in MATLAB, and is required because methods needn't dispatch only on the first input)